# Regular expression combination of quantifiers *?

Tags: regex

What does this combination of quantifiers `*?` mean?

Use this as the following example:

```
([0-9][AB]*?)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reference - What does this regex mean?](/q/22937618/r90527)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a non-greedy match.  In `[AB]*?`, the regex looks for as few occurrences of `[AB]` as needed to make the overall regex match the searched string, whereas the greedy version `[AB]*` looks for as many occurrences as possible.  It is a feature of Perl's [regexes](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreref.html#QUANTIFIERS), and hence available in [PCRE](http://www.pcre.org/) (Perl Compatible Regular Expressions) (see [repetition](http://www.pcre.org/current/doc/html/pcre2pattern.html#SEC17)) and other systems that look to Perl for their definition.

The PCRE page gives an example:

> The classic example of where [greediness] gives problems is in trying to match comments in C programs. These appear between `/*` and `*/` and within the comment, individual `*` and `/` characters may appear. An attempt to match C comments by applying the pattern:
>
> ```
> /\*.*\*/
> ```
>
> to the string
>
> ```
> /* first comment */  not comment  /* second comment */
> ```
>
> fails, because it matches the entire string owing to the greediness of the `.*` item.
>
> If a quantifier is followed by a question mark, it ceases to be greedy, and instead matches the minimum number of times possible, so the pattern
>
> ```
> /\*.*?\*/
> ```
>
> does the right thing with the C comments.

Answer (score 2):

Jonathan already explained the difference, but here's an example that might help you understand what's happening here.

Given the string "9AB":

- `([0-9][AB]*?)` matches only "9A" because it stop as soon as "A" matched (lazy)
- `([0-9][AB]*)` matches the whole string ("9AB") because it consumes "A" and successes to match the following "B" (greedy)

Note that the second one will match a digit, followed by zero or more (unlimited) number of "A" or "B"s.

Comment: Thanks for the example, Maroun. I tried this example in python and instead of getting what you proposed, I'm getting a result of "9". This was my code:

x = re.search(r'[0-9][AB]*?', '9AB')
print x.group(0)

Comment: Which one would be the correct result, "9" or "9A"?

Comment: 9 is correct because zero matches of `[AB]` is allowed.  Greediness mainly matters when there's something after the greedy quantifier.